# .htaccess XML-Sitemap Redirect for multi-domain

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-8, sitemap

My homepage is accessible via 2 different domains.

**1: https://example.at**

**2: https://example.de**

I manually created for each site the sitemap.xml which is located in the root directory of my page. (**sitemap1.xml / sitemap2.xml**)

After entering the URL **example.at/sitemap.xml** or **example.de/sitemap.xml** I need a redirect to the correct .xml file.

**1:** https://example.at/sitemap.xml => https://example.at/sitemap1.xml

**2:** https://example.de/sitemap.xml => https://example.de/sitemap2.xml

I tried the follwing redirect-rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/sitemap\.xml$
RewriteRule .* https://example.at/sitemap1.xml [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/sitemap\.xml$
RewriteRule .* https://example.de/sitemap2.xml [R=301,L]
```

No matter if I enter the **.de** or the **.at** address I will be forwarded to:
**https://example.at/sitemap1.xml**.

I have no experience with rewrite-rules so I used:
https://www.webcellent.com/tools/modrewrite/

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.at$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /sitemap.xml
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.at/sitemap1.xml [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.de$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /sitemap.xml
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.de/sitemap2.xml [R=301,L]
```

**Edit:** Might have been a caching issue